# JavaScript: Simple way to check if variable is equal to one of two or more values?

Tags: javascript, comparison

Is there an easier way to determine if a variable is equal to a range of values, such as:

```
if x === 5 || 6
```

rather than something obtuse like:

```
if x === 5 || x === 6
```

?

Comment: Why do you consider the latter obtuse?

Comment: Because I need to write some code that checks if a variable has one of 20 values, namely, if x = "New York" || "Austin" || "Alberta", etc.

Comment: @AdamTempleton: Either put all your values in an array, and then use `indexOf`, or you can also use a regex `/^(New York|Austin|Alberta)$/.test(x)`.

Comment: @AdamTempleton in which case you should rewrite your question to say so.  You specifically say _two_ in the subject.

Comment: Use s = new Set([5, 6]); s.has(x);. Not sure why I can't anser this question.

Comment: While the answers are ultimately the same, the intent of the questions are very different, and I believe that pointing people to a question about arrays when they ask about how to check for multiple values does a disservice to askers. I'd rather point them to this question.

Comment: [javascript - Check variable equality against a list of values - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728144/check-variable-equality-against-a-list-of-values) is a better duplicate.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You can stash your values inside an array and check whether the variable exists in the array by using [`[].indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```
if([5, 6].indexOf(x) > -1) {
  // ...
}
```

If `-1` is returned then the variable doesn't exist in the array.

Comment: This does not work in IE < 9. See [MDN's Array#indexOf Compatibility section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Compatibility) for code that you can insert to actually make it work in IE. However, unless you are using this in several places, it would probably be faster just to use `a == 1 || a == 2`.

Comment: Alternatively, if you are using a JS framework, both MooTools and Prototype ensure Array#indexOf exists. jQuery, on the other hand, provides its own implementation in the form of [`$.inArray`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/). I'm not familiar with any other frameworks, but I'm sure they all include such functionality in some manner.

Comment: A bit more description of the code would have been nice.

Comment: And now we have i.e. ```['a','b'].includes('a')```

Answer (score 24):

Depends on what sort of test you're performing. If you've got static strings, this is very easy to check via regular expressions:

```
if (/^[56ab]$/.test(item)) {
//-or-
if (/^(foo|bar|baz|fizz|buzz)$/.test(item)) {
    doStuff();
} else {
    doOtherStuff();
}
```

If you've got a small set of values (string or number), you can use a `switch`:

```
switch (item) {
case 1:
case 2:
case 3:
    doStuff();
    break;
default:
    doOtherStuff();
    break;
}
```

If you've got a long list of values, you should probably use an array with [`~arr.indexOf(item)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10584043/497418), or `arr.contains(item)`:

```
vals = [1,3,18,3902,...];
if (~vals.indexOf(item)) {
    doStuff();
} else {
    doOtherStuff();
}
```

<sub>Unfortunately `Array.prototype.indexOf` isn't supported in some browsers. Fortunately [a polyfill is available](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf). If you're going through the trouble of polyfilling `Array.prototype.indexOf`, you might as well add `Array.prototype.contains`.</sub>

Depending on how you're associating data, you could store a dynamic list of strings within an object as a map to other relevant information:

```
var map = {
    foo: bar,
    fizz: buzz
}
if (item in map) {
//-or-
if (map.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
    doStuff(map[item]);
} else {
    doOtherStuff();
}
```

<sub>`in` will check the entire prototype chain while `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty` will only check the object, so be aware that they are different.</sub>

Answer (score 17):

It's perfectly fine. If you have a longer list of values, perhaps you can use the following instead:

```
if ([5,6,7,8].indexOf(x) > -1) {
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes. You can use your own function. This example uses [`.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
var foo = [ 5, 6 ].some(function(val) {
     return val === x;
   });

foo; // true
```

Comment: Gave you an upvote for .some, which I'd never seen before!

Comment: I think .some is only IE9 or up.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I've decided to use:

```
Object.prototype.isin = function() {
    for(var i = arguments.length; i--;) {
        var a = arguments[i];
        if(a.constructor === Array) {
            for(var j = a.length; j--;)
                if(a[j] == this) return true;
        }
        else if(a == this) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

You would use it like this:

```
var fav   = 'pear',
    fruit = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'pear'],
    plu   = [4152, 4231, 3030, 4409];

if (fav.isin(fruit, plu, 'eggs', 'cheese')) {
    //do something cool
}
```

The advantages are:

- it works in IE < 9;
- it reads naturally from left to right;
- you can feed it arrays or separate values.

If you don't want to allow type coercion (`indexOf` does not), change the two `==` to `===`. As it stands:

```
fav = "4231";
plu.indexOf(fav) //-1
fav.isin(plu)    //true
```

Answer (score 2):

no, there might be a few tricks that are case specific but in general i write code like this:

```
if (someVariable === 1 ||
    someVariable === 2 ||
    someVariable === 7 ||
    someVariable === 12 ||
    someVariable === 14 ||
    someVariable === 19) {

    doStuff();
    moreStuff();

} else {
    differentStuff();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is no. You can use a switch statement, which is easier to read if you are comparing a lot of string values, but using it for two values wouldn't look any better.

Answer (score -2):

**[Edit] this seems to work, but as Dan pointed out, it is actually a false positive. Do not use this method. I leave it here for educational purposes.**

Easiest way I know :

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5];

if(3 in a) alert("true"); // will alert true
```

Tested in Chrome console. Not sure if it works in other browsers.

Comment: That example works by accident. Try `3 in [1, 3]` - it will return `false` because there is no element *with the index 3* in the array `[1, 3]`. For that matter, `3 in ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']` will return true.

Comment: Damn, so it's a false positive. Thanks for that.