# Javascript find with multiple conditions with includes fails

Tags: javascript

I have the following array

```
let registrations = [
   {user:1, reg_on:'12/02/2009'},
   {user:10, reg_on:'11/02/2009'},
   {user:5, reg_on:'11/02/2109'},
     ///others
 ]
```

So now am trying to find one record where user is 1 or 5 thats the first

SO i have done the following which works

```
let final =  registrations.find(reg=>reg.user === 1 ||reg.user === 5);
```

The above works but it becomes tedious if there is a need to add more filter parameters like reg.user === 10

So i have tried refactoring this like

```
 let final =  registrations.find(reg=>reg.user.includes([1,5,10]));
```

But now the one having includes doesnt work. What am i missing out?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: Simple way to check if variable is equal to two or more values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12116326/javascript-simple-way-to-check-if-variable-is-equal-to-two-or-more-values)

Comment: Your includes is backwards.

Comment: @HereticMonkey the answer youve provided is different from my scope, In my question i have specified that am interested in using includes, the answer youve provided uses indexOf, and also it also recommends using what am doing but my question is about refactoring the code.

Comment: Then [How do I check if an array includes an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/237104/215552) is the appropriate duplicate...

Comment: You can have a set of allowed user and than use `allowedUser.has(reg.user)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make an array of user numbers to find, and check whether it `.includes` the `reg.user`:

```
registrations.find(reg => [1, 5, 10].includes(reg.user));
```

```js
let registrations = [
   {user:1, reg_on:'12/02/2009'},
   {user:10, reg_on:'11/02/2009'},
   {user:5, reg_on:'11/02/2109'},
     ///others
];

let final = registrations.find(reg => [1, 5, 10].includes(reg.user));

console.log(final);
```