# Right behavior to write in HTML using Angular 4

Tags: html, angular

Is the following right code to right or the alternate way mentioned below. Also how can I optimize it by using some logic in it's associated typescript file?

```
<div class="ag-grid-title content-sec-text" style="height: 29px;">
    <span *ngIf="lifeCycleStatus === lifeCycleStatusList.SETUP_COMPLETE || lifeCycleStatus = lifeCycleStatusList.CREATING">
        <img src="../../../assets/images/icons-svg/reachable.svg" style="height:15px" class="svgicon"> 
        {{lifeCycleStatus}}
    </span>
    <span *ngIf="lifeCycleStatus === lifeCycleStatusList.CREATE_FAILED || lifeCycleStatus === lifeCycleStatusList.DEL || 
    lifeCycleStatus === lifeCycleStatusList.DEL_FAILED">
        <img src="../../../assets/images/icons-svg/deleting.svg" style="height:15px" class="svgicon"> 
        {{lifeCycleStatus}}
    </span>
```

Or the following should be enough leaving lifeCycleStatus = inside the || everytime.

```
<div class="ag-grid-title content-sec-text" style="height: 29px;">
    <span *ngIf="lifeCycleStatus === lifeCycleStatusList.SETUP_COMPLETE || lifeCycleStatusList.CREATING">
        <img src="../../../assets/images/icons-svg/reachable.svg" style="height:15px" class="svgicon"> 
        {{lifeCycleStatus}}
    </span>
    <span *ngIf="lifeCycleStatus === lifeCycleStatusList.CREATE_FAILED || lifeCycleStatusList.DEL || 
    lifeCycleStatus = lifeCycleStatusList.DEL_FAILED">
        <img src="../../../assets/images/icons-svg/deleting.svg" style="height:15px" class="svgicon"> 
        {{lifeCycleStatus}}
    </span>
```

Logic in the .ts file

```
private lifeCycleStatusList = {
     SETUP_COMPLETE: 'Setup Complete', CREATING: 'Creating',
     CREATE_FAILED: 'Create Failed', DEL: 'Deleting', DEL_FAILED: 'Deleting Failed', UNKNOWN: 'Unknown'
};
```

Comment: You are not doing any logical comparison.You are just assigning

Comment: `=` is assignment; `==` or `===` is comparison. Also, you can't compare to multiple things using `||` like that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: Simple way to check if variable is equal to two or more values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12116326/javascript-simple-way-to-check-if-variable-is-equal-to-two-or-more-values)

Comment: That's right, my bad should be === instead, but how do I improve using some logic

Comment: Make use of `pipe` which will make your code less verbose more readable and more optimized