# How to stop loop if only one of these isn't true?

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I have a while function that will run in auto mode if auto mode is activated (`checkBox.checked`)

The problem is this code only stops once both a and b are greater than my game limit # (`bestof.value`). I want it to stop once only one of these is not true.

When I use `while(a || b < bestof.value)` it times out until the stack reaches its limit. It also returns no values.

```
if ( checkBox.checked == true ) {
    while( a && b < bestof.value ) {
       myFunction();
    }
};
```

Any idea how I can solve this?

Comment: `while (a < bestof.value && b < bestof.value)`. Javascript doesn't work like English.

Comment: _"once both a and b are greater than my game limit"_ - That's not correct. The loop will end when `a` is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) and `b` is equal or greater than `bestof.value`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript: Simple way to check if variable is equal to two or more values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12116326/javascript-simple-way-to-check-if-variable-is-equal-to-two-or-more-values)

Comment: Note that you have mismatched brackets (two opening curly brackets, at the end of the `if`, and at the end of the `while`, and one closing curly bracket).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to say that a and b are supposed to be smaller than bestof.value?

Unfortunately that is not how the syntax works, the && seperates statements, so basically you are saying while a is true and b is smaler than...

What you need is this:

```js
if (checkBox.checked == true){
    while(a < bestof.value && b < bestof.value){
    myFunction();
};
```

As you realized correctly, your code only stops as soon a and b are above the value, since it checks if a exists and b is over the value, so basically your trigger is when b surpasses the value.

Another example:

```js
let a = 1
let b
if (a) {
  console.log("a exists")
}
if (b) {
  console.log("b exists")
}
```

As you can see "b exists" is not being printed, and this is basically what you ask ur while loop before the `&&`, if a exists ...

Comment: the 2 win values (a and b) should both < game limit #, and if one is false then loop ends. I'm pretty new to JS so excuse the ignorance.

Comment: One who invests time to learn something new is not ignorant no matter the stage of the learning process

Answer (score 0):

**Mistakes you made:**

1. `while` condition for "*I want loop to stop once one of a or b become greater than my game limit*" is same as "*run loop till both a and b is less then limit*":

```js
while(a < bestof.value && b < bestof.value) { ... }
```

2. It's unnecessary to convert/compare `if` condition to boolean on your own, JS will do it automatically, so this is enough:

```js
if (checkBox.checked) { ... }
```

3. You missed '}'. Always compare count of open and close brackets if your IDE/editor don't do it.

```js
if (checkBox.checked == true){
    while(a && b < bestof.value) {
        myFunction();
//   ↑ here you forget to close while body
};
```

**Also:** You always can stop any loop with [break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) keyword:

```js
white(condition) {
  if (needToStop) { break; }
}
```

**Conclusion:** your code should look like this:

```js
if (checkBox.checked) {
    while(a < bestof.value && b < bestof.value) {
        myFunction();
    }
};
```